# MySQL function/script to send data to a webhook when table XYZ is updated

Tags: python, mysql, database, windows, automation

I assume the entire thing "Sending data to a webhook when a row is updated in XYZ table" wouldn't be possible via just MySQL query. However, I am trying to figure out a way to automate the process. Can anyone share some example ways this can be done?

Here's what I intend to automate:

- Whenever any row is updated in table XYZ
- The script should send out data from table ABC, DEF (tables that are connected to the earilier XYZ table) to a webhook URL.

The biggest issue I have is that this MySQL database is locally stored so I have to run the script locally, otherwise, I'd used Zapier for this.

Just need some light on what programs or scripts I should be using.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the code you provided.

Answer (score 3):

The options are:

- Modify the client application code that updates the database. After the transaction commits, then notify the webhook from the client app. It's important to do it after the commit, or else you could notify the webhook about data that is subsequently rolled back.
- Use a binary log tailer, for example [Debezium](https://debezium.io). This has a couple of advantages: changes are added to the binary log only on commit, so the binlog tailer never sees changes that were rolled back. This does not require you to modify your client code. It works even if data is updated by several clients, or even by a human using an interactive client.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you cannot do this with pure MySQL: unless you add a somewhat dodgy extension to your MySQL server it has no way to originate any operation.

You could create a trigger on UPDATE (and perhaps another on INSERT) on that `XYZ` table.  The trigger would INSERT a row into a new table called, maybe `webhook_queue`.

A separate webhook program would, running every few seconds, SELECT, then DELETE all rows from that `webhook_queue` table, then send each webhook.  There's obviously a latency problem with this approach: webhooks won't be sent until the webhook program wakes up and does its work.

If that won't work for you, you probably have to modify your application code to invoke the webhook as it UPDATEs each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL PROCEDURE and cURL to send request to your script anywhere in web or on localhost webserver.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE notify_webhook()
BEGIN
  DECLARE url VARCHAR(255);
  SET url = 'http://example.com/webhook';

  SET @json = JSON_OBJECT('event', 'delete', 'timestamp', NOW());

  SET @result = curl('POST', url, @json);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

And then create a TRIGGER in your table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_delete
AFTER DELETE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  CALL notify_webhook();
END;
```

If you need to provide id to procedure you can write this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE notify_webhook(IN deleted_id INT)

SET @json = JSON_OBJECT('event', 'delete', 'timestamp', NOW(), 'delete_id', deleted_id);
```

IN TRIGGER

```
CALL notify_webhook(OLD.id);
```

This is example for delete trigger, but you can ajust it to AFTER UPDATE